# Create ms sql database with some flags

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to create a database through powershell. The problem I'm encountering is that I want this database to be created with some flags enabled (for example "Allow Snapshot Isolation"). I do not know how to do that and I'm having trouble finding out.

What I have done so far:

```
$SqlSecurePassword = $SqlServerPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$Connection = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection("(local)", $SqlServerUser, $SqlServerPassword)
$Server = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($Connection)
$Db = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($Server, $DatabaseName)
$Db.Create()
```

Comment: How about executing the needed `ALTER DATABASE` statements after creating the DB?

Comment: That is also an option, but I was hoping the flags were part of the object, Something like `$Db.SomeFlag = $True`

Comment: hmmm, turns out they actually can be set like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can just call `$Db.SomeFlag = $someValue` and that works, for example:
`$Db.AutoShrink = $True`

Answer (score 1):

I would wirte a SQL-Script to create the database, just like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE [test]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'test', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf' , SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'test_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON(INCREMENTAL = OFF)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO
USE [test]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY') ALTER DATABASE [test] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT
GO
```

and then execute this file with powershell... Is that an option for you?

Comment: Of course you do not have to specify all these options.. that's just what SSMS does when you script the creation of a database.

Comment: while this would work, It is impractical in my case since I am using a parametrized Powershell script file which gets the flags as input. This would involve a lot of writing....

Comment: ok what if you just exeute this if necessary after database creation: `ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
GO`

Comment: That's also an option

Answer (score 1):

This script demonstrates all the flags for the default database creation T-SQL in SQL 2016:

```
$DB=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database]::new($Server,"TemporaryDB")
# CONTAINMENT = NONE
$DB.ContainmentType=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ContainmentType]::None
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
$DB.CompatibilityLevel=130
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
$DB.AnsiNullDefault=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
$DB.AnsiNullsEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
$DB.AnsiPaddingEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
$DB.AnsiWarningsEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
$DB.ArithmeticAbortEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
$DB.AutoClose=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
$DB.AutoShrink=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON(INCREMENTAL = OFF)
$DB.AutoCreateStatisticsEnabled=$true
$DB.AutoCreateIncrementalStatisticsEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
$DB.AutoUpdateStatisticsEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
$DB.CloseCursorsOnCommitEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
$DB.LocalCursorsDefault=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
$DB.ConcatenateNullYieldsNull=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
$DB.NumericRoundAbortEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
$DB.QuotedIdentifiersEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
$DB.RecursiveTriggersEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
$DB.BrokerEnabled=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
$DB.AutoUpdateStatisticsAsync=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
$DB.DateCorrelationOptimization=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
$DB.IsParameterizationForced=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
$DB.IsReadCommittedSnapshotOn=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET  READ_WRITE 
$DB.ReadOnly=$false
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET RECOVERY FULL 
$DB.RecoveryModel=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RecoveryModel]::Full
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET  MULTI_USER 
$DB.UserAccess=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseUserAccess]::Multiple
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
$DB.PageVerify=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PageVerify]::Checksum
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
$DB.TargetRecoveryTime=60
#ALTER DATABASE [TemporaryDB] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
$DB.DelayedDurability=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DelayedDurability]::Disabled
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 0;
$DB.MaxDop=0
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET MAXDOP = PRIMARY;
$DB.MaxDopForSecondary=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseScopedConfigurationOnOff]::Primary
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = OFF;
$DB.LegacyCardinalityEstimation=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseScopedConfigurationOnOff]::Off
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = PRIMARY;
$DB.LegacyCardinalityEstimationForSecondary=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseScopedConfigurationOnOff]::Primary
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = ON;
$DB.ParameterSniffing=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseScopedConfigurationOnOff]::On
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = PRIMARY;
$DB.ParameterSniffingForSecondary=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseScopedConfigurationOnOff]::Primary
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = OFF;
$DB.QueryOptimizerHotfixes=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseScopedConfigurationOnOff]::Off
#ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = PRIMARY;
$DB.QueryOptimizerHotfixesForSecondary=[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseScopedConfigurationOnOff]::Primary
```